# Search bar with UITableView inside UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift2, uisearchbar

I'm trying to make a search filter in my results of a json file.

So i have the following code

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON



class checkViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{



    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkTable: UITableView!


     var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]()

    var filteredData = [[String:AnyObject]]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkTable.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
        filteredData = arrRes



        Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://example.com/search", parameters: ["q": "", "type": "name"])
            .responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
                if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                    let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
                    print(swiftyJsonVar)
                    if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["data"].arrayObject {
                        self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                    }
                    if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                        self.checkTable.reloadData()
                    }
                }                   
        }    
    }        
     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }        
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {         
            return arrRes.count           
    }       
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("checkInCellView", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = dict["name"] as? String
        return cell
    }


}
```

I'm trying to insert `UISearchResultsUpdating` in my Class but i get an error that is not a member. So i'm trying with `UISearchBarDelegate` but i can only find a way in an array of [String] and NOT for [[String:AnyObject]] with this example

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    let data = ["New York, NY", "Los Angeles, CA", "Chicago, IL", "Houston, TX",
        "Philadelphia, PA", "Phoenix, AZ", "San Diego, CA", "San Antonio, TX",
        "Dallas, TX", "Detroit, MI", "San Jose, CA", "Indianapolis, IN",
        "Jacksonville, FL", "San Francisco, CA", "Columbus, OH", "Austin, TX",
        "Memphis, TN", "Baltimore, MD", "Charlotte, ND", "Fort Worth, TX"]

    var filteredData: [String]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
        filteredData = data
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableCell") as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData.count
    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? data : data.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
            return dataString.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
        })

    }

    // This method updates filteredData based on the text in the Search Box
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        // When there is no text, filteredData is the same as the original data
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            filteredData = data
        } else {
            // The user has entered text into the search box
            // Use the filter method to iterate over all items in the data array
            // For each item, return true if the item should be included and false if the
            // item should NOT be included
            filteredData = data.filter({(dataItem: String) -> Bool in
                // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
                if dataItem.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make it also for [[String:AnyObject]] ???

Because if i try to do this i get an error

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? arrRes : arrRes.filter({(dataString: [String:AnyObject]) -> Bool in
        return dataString.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
    })

}
```

Value of type '[String : AnyObject]' has no member 'rangeOfString'

Any idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you will get idea from below code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var MyStringArray: [String] = ["ABC","XYZ","SomeData"]

    let strDemo : String = "SomeData"

    for indexNo in 0..<MyStringArray.count 
    {

        if MyStringArray[indexNo].rangeOfString(strDemo) != nil
        {
            print("found")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Not found")
        }
    }

}
```